# Obtener milisegundos de una fecha dada en MySQL

Tags: mysql

¿existe alguna función propia de MySQL que me de los milisegundos de una fecha o cómo tendría que hacer una? Llevo algo de rato buscando si tenia una función como en JavaScript que es getTime() que devuelve el número de milisegundos desde 1970/01/01 pero creo que no lo hay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con la función UNIX_TIMESTAMP() de Mysql. Ejemplo:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(campoFecha) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2018-04-05 00:00:00") 
FROM table
```

Comment: Gracias bro  :), después de todo si había una función debo buscar bien en la documentación, no me di cuenta de esta.

Answer (score 1):

**Puedes utilizar UNIX_TIMESTAMP, para obtener el rango de diferencias entre 2 fechas**

```
SET @fechaUno = '2018-01-01 00:00:00';
SET @fechaDos = '2009-01-01 00:00:00';

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@fechaUno) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@fechaDos);
```

> La función UNIX_TIMESTAMP, toma como valor de partida por defecto de
>   '1970-01-01 00:00:00', en formato de horario GMT,que otorga una
>   medición de tiempo con base a relojes de caracter atómico, considera que si no asignas un valor por defecto a dicha función tomará la fecha y hora actual.

Se usa GMT, o mejor conocido como horario medio de greenwich el cual es una medida de horario estandar internacional

Para que este cálculo te sirva necesitas que las variables contengan el formato **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**

Al final te puedes auxiliar de esta herramienta de google, para transformar la cantidad obtenida de segundos a días, meses, años o lo que requieras

[CONVERTIDOR](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=de%20segundos%20a%20dias&oq=de%20segundos)